# Postgres Trigger is not firing. Syntax help is appreciated

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to mark a boolean column on a different table to true upon the insertion of a matching record.

Here's what I've got:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION mark_as_sold() RETURNS trigger AS
  $BODY$
BEGIN
  UPDATE listing
  set listing.sold = true;
  WHERE listing.id = NEW.listing_id;
  RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER update_child_after_update
AFTER INSERT
ON transaction
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE mark_as_sold();
```

When I create a record on the transaction table, nothing happens. I'm stumped. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was messing up my relations. Here's the proper code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mark_as_sold()
RETURNS TRIGGER
AS $$
BEGIN
  UPDATE listing
  set sold = true
  WHERE listing.id = NEW.listing_id;
  RETURN NEW;

RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON "transaction"
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE mark_as_sold();
```